# Get glyph names from TTF file in C#

Tags: c#, fonts, glyph

I have a TTF file (the file that can be downloaded from https://materialdesignicons.com/ to be more precise) and I want to get the name and unicode numeric value of each glyph contained in it (something like this site does https://andreinitescu.github.io/IconFont2Code/ but I'm obviously to dumb to read the essential code parts from his Github project). I **do not** want the name of the font or anything just the name of each individual glyph.

I can see the names when I open the file with for example Notepad++ but I can not identify a pattern which I could use to get the names programmatically.

I have now searched the internet for more than a day straight and I can't find any helpful answers. It can't be **that** hard to get it working - or can it?

Comment: That IconFont2Code project uses https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js

Comment: That's right but this won't help me either when I'm using C#.

Comment: Right, but it might help you with writing your own C# TTF parser (which it looks like you're going to have to do)

Comment: There's a C# wrapper for freetype over on https://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont, which should let you get anything that's stored in the font.